# SpringBoot2 OAuth2 dependencies - migrating from springBoot1.5.6

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, pcf

We are migrating from SpringBoot1.5.6 to springBoot2 and having compile issue on OAuth2 libraries, Based on the documentation it appears we are including the correct libraries - however it failes to recognize oauth2 libraries (Eg @EnableResourceServer.. etc.)

Below is the POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring-cloud-services.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring-cloud-services.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-services.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe corrupt maven download?

Comment: I don't this it's a corrupt download. When I comment out spring-cloud-services-dependencies the code compiles .. however the application throws an error during start up  - org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration'

Comment: You'll need to contact PCF support about spring-cloud-services

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace `spring-boot-starter-security` with `spring-cloud-starter-security` under the *dependencies* section